# selecting with random date ranges

Tags: mysql

I am trying to achieve selecting from a table with random date ranges. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp 
BETWEEN <random_date> AND <the_same_random_date> - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

That way I should be selecting an interval of 1 day of a random date. Any suggestions?

**Update:** So the random queries might has the same effect as following ones:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp 
BETWEEN '2011-08-05 00:00' AND '2011-08-05 00:00' - INTERVAL 1 DAY

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp 
BETWEEN '2011-08-12 14:30' AND '2011-08-12 14:30' - INTERVAL 1 DAY

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp 
BETWEEN '2011-05-11 06:15' AND '2011-05-11 06:15' - INTERVAL 1 DAY

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp 
BETWEEN '2011-03-03 21:11' AND '2011-03-03 21:11' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Do you need the same random date for all rows?

Comment: I need the same random date for the same query. I have updated the question, can you please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    my_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(RAND() * 2147483647) random_date) rd
WHERE 
    timestamp BETWEEN (rd.random_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND rd.random_date
```

Answer (score 1):

When using BETWEEN, the lesser (earlier) value must come first.  For example, instead of

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp 
BETWEEN '2011-08-05 00:00' AND '2011-08-05 00:00' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

You would want to use

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp 
BETWEEN '2011-08-05 00:00' - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND '2011-08-05 00:00'
```

Are you asking how to use MySQL to generate those random dates?  Or were you just wondering why your query wasn't working?  If you were looking to generate random dates, Karolis' answer should be peachy for you.

Comment: I was looking for Karolis' answer. but thank you for the tip "the lesser (earlier) value must come first". it also saved me a good deal of time